# $-1$ as sum of $k$ squares with $k$ least postive integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{C}$ such that it do not contains $i$.

Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $-1$ is sum of $k$ squares in $F$.

A theorem of Kaplansky (1953) asserts that $k$ is either $1,2,4,8$ or a multiple of $8$. Kaplansky also points out in his corresponding paper that $k=16$ will not occur.

Since this paper is more than 50 year old, it seems that there may be further development related to the above fact. This raised a question to me:

**Question.** For $F$ as above, is there now complete determination of all possible value of $k$?

---

It should be noted that when field has characteristic $p$, then $k$ is either $1$ or $2$; hence consider fields of only characteristic zero; among them, I am considering more natural and specific fields - finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which do not contain $i$ and ask for all possible values of $k$ whether estimated till today? If yes, can one suggest some reference for it, possibly a book?

Comment: A. R. Rajwade, *Squares*, CUP, 1993.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes sense for any field $F$, for which the *level*, denoted by $s(F)$ (from the German *Stufe*), is defined as the least positive integer $k$ such that $-1$ is a sum of $k$ squares in $F^*$ whenever such an integer
exists, and $\infty$  otherwise. For fields of positive characteristic, $s(F)$  can take only the values $1$ and $2$, depending just on whether $-1$ is a square in $F^*$ or not. Fields of level $\infty$, called *real fields*, are exactly those on which an ordering can be defined (e.g. $\mathbf Q$ or $\mathbf R$). Fields of finite level are also called *nonreal fields*.

The complete solution to the problem of the possible values of $s(F)$ was given by A. Pfister at the beginning of the $60$s, inspiring a big part of later advances in the theory of quadratic forms, e.g. the developments around the so called *Pfister forms*, see T.Y. Lam's book "The algebraic theory of quadratic forms", Benjamin (1973). Pfister proved that the level of a nonreal field is always a power of $2$, and further that, if $F$ is any real field  and $n\ge 0$, then the function field of the projective quadric $X_0^2 + ... +X_{2^n}^2 = 0$ over $F$ has level $2^n$. These were the first examples of nonreal fields of level $\ge 4$ and, actually, still no examples of an essentially different kind are known. The standard examples of fields of level $1,2$ and $4$, are respectively $\mathbf C, \mathbf F_3$ and $\mathbf Q_2$. But note that it remains a diffcult problem to determine the level of a given field of characteristic zero. For an overview on what is known about levels of common types of fields, see *op. cit.*, chapter XI, section 2 .